# Append multiple child div to parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to append all the child divs to the bottom of parent div.
Here is my code so far:

```css
.valign {

  display: inline-block;

  width: 100%;

  position: relative;

}

.block {

  display: inline-block;

  max-width: 75%;

}

.red {

  float: left;

  padding: 10px;

  background-color: red;

}

.yellow {

  float: left;

  padding: 10px;

  background-color: yellow;

}

.green {

  float: left;

  padding: 10px;

  background-color: green;

}
```

```html
<div class="valign">
  <div>
    <div class="block red">my bottom aligned div 1</div>
    <div class="block yellow">my bottom aligned div 2</div>
    <div class="block green">my bottom aligned div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsBin: http://jsbin.com/bahasotofo/edit?html,css,js,output

I've gone through multiple suggestions for the same question but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: What you want isn't possible with pure CSS. You would need to use some JS.

Comment: Yes I used JS to append child to parent div. Same as from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp but still not working :(

Comment: I think so you are not very clear with what you want, because already you have some child elements. And now if you are planning to add more and then align then at bottom of parent div then you have go with JS.

Comment: I created parentDiv in JS itself and trying to appendChild to parentDiv. I've applied CSS to both parent and child div as mentioned in my code.

Comment: What do you really mean? Are you talking about CREATING more divs or ALIGNING children position? Please elaborate or create an image or show similar demo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every child to be appended vertically, use this CSS:

```
.block {     
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 75%;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Well this whole thing seems kinda redundant. Divs are block elements by default so why the need to float and clear?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it creates a p tag inside of your .red class. Is this is what you are looking for.

```
var rd = document.querySelector(".red");
var rdp = document.createElement("p");
var rdpt = document.createTextNode("my bottom aligned div 1");
rdp.appendChild(rdpt);
rd.appendChild(rdp);
```